# Steps to build a web app connected to SQL server

Tags: javascript, html, api, d3.js, web-applications

First time asking a question here and I feel like a noob for asking this but I figured I might get some helpful info here. I work as a data analyst creating reports in Tableau and working with SQL server. I've had some minimal experience programming in Java, Javascript, and HTML. D3 has really peaked my interest as a powerful language that could be used to create more complex/creative dashboards. I essentially would like to use D3 and Javascript to create dashboards based off data housed on SQL server but having never built a web app I'm a little overwhelmed at what all I would need to do to accomplish such a feat. I know I would need an API etc, I'm just not sure of the steps needed to make it all happen. Can anyone explain to me what I would need to do (step by step) from a "birds eye view", so I have a good idea of what direction I need to go in? Thanks.

Comment: "D3 has really peaked my interest as a powerful language" — It's a library, not a language.

Comment: What backend would you be using? If it's Java I personally have no idea. But if you're willing to experiment with NodeJS you would basically only need some library like this: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql.

Comment: @Quentin My bad. D3 is a library, language was used incorrectly there

Comment: @HairLessDude I would probably use NodeJS, not java

Comment: It's what @Quentin said.

Comment: @HairLessDude — `node-sql` isn't going to be very useful for connecting to Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks. Assumng I go with Node.js (which is very likely) what library/languges are common to interact with SQL server (#3).

Answer (score 3):

1. Pick a programming language (e.g. Java or JavaScript).
2. Pick a web server that you can run server side code written in that language on (e.g. Tomcat or Node.js).
3. Find a library for that programming language that can interact with the SQL server you are using.
4. Write a server side program (in your language of choice) that can:

   1. read the data from an HTTP request.
   2. use it to query your database.
   3. return that data (probably formatted as JSON) in the HTTP response.

(Node.js isn't technically a web server, but the usual way to run server side code written in JS is to write a program in JS that has a built-in web server and then run that program with Node.js).